# How can I remove flash player forever from Tor?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, plugin

Somehow flash player has gotten inside Tor and I do not like it. It offered one-click enable flash, but it doesn't state its risks and how long it will be enabled. I don't want to give up privacy for any videos, in fact, I want flash player to never attach itself to Tor browser in the first place. I want to have no way of enabling flash player in Tor browser as long as it does not offer privacy by design(read: forever). And also how did this function appear? Was it the Tor update or the flash player update? I can't believe they did not even notify the users how much privacy they give up by this feature.

Comment: *Somehow flash player has gotten inside tor...* -- I think by "tor" you actually mean the Tor Browser Bundle - i.e. Tor client bundled with securely pre-configured Firefox in a single package.

Answer (score 6):

Delete the Tor browser folder and reinstall the Tor browser bundle. Flash is not part of the TBB by default and can't be added without user intervention.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Windows 8? If so, I have the same problem. Apparently, Flash installs itself into your Windows 8 system through a software update.
I found this walk-through on how to get rid of it from your machine. Hope it helps:
http://betanews.com/2013/01/10/you-can-remove-adobe-flash-from-windows-heres-how/

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what OS you're using. If you're using Windows, you can just prevent plugins from loading from the Windows registry in the Tor Browser (which is actually Firefox). I have tested this on Windows 7 with the Tor Browser Bundle v. 3.5.

To prevent the Tor Browser from loading plugins start by typing `about:plugins` into the browser to see what plugins you have installed. In this case, you should only see Flash installed.

Next, type `about:config` into your browser and then set the preference `plugin.scan.plid.all` to false. If you check `about:plugins` again, you will see that Flash is no longer listed. When you relaunch the Tor Browser, Flash will be gone.